# How to declare interval infinity in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, infinity

It seems that we can't currently case infinity as an interval.

While trying:
SELECT 'infinity'::interval;`
we get

```
SQL Error [22007]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type interval: "infinity"
```

How could I specify a max value for an interval?

I tried comparing 2 infinity timestamps

```
SELECT ('-infinity'::timestamp + '1 day'::INTERVAL)::timestamp without time zone at time zone 'UTC' 
- 'infinity'::timestamp  without time zone at time zone 'UTC';
```

but now getting

```
SQL Error [22008]: ERROR: cannot subtract infinite timestamps
```

Any idea?

Comment: "*a timestamp can be converted into an interval*" - what makes you assume that? Notice that **two** timestamps can form an interval, a single timestamp doesn't.

Comment: oh, true, I made some new tests and updated above with the results

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that is true. You cannot represent infinite intervals with the `interval` data type.